# How does Eric Niebler's implementation of std::is_function work?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, type-traits

Last week Eric Niebler [tweeted](https://twitter.com/ericniebler/status/852192542653329408) a very compact implementation for the [`std::is_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) traits class:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int I> struct priority_tag : priority_tag<I - 1> {};
template<> struct priority_tag<0> {};

// Function types here:
template<typename T>
char(&is_function_impl_(priority_tag<0>))[1];

// Array types here:
template<typename T, typename = decltype((*(T*)0)[0])>
char(&is_function_impl_(priority_tag<1>))[2];

// Anything that can be returned from a function here (including
// void and reference types):
template<typename T, typename = T(*)()>
char(&is_function_impl_(priority_tag<2>))[3];

// Classes and unions (including abstract types) here:
template<typename T, typename = int T::*>
char(&is_function_impl_(priority_tag<3>))[4];

template <typename T>
struct is_function
    : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(is_function_impl_<T>(priority_tag<3>{})) == 1>
{};
```

But how does it work?

Comment: Why not just have the first function return `std::true_type` and the rest return `std::false_type` and then have `is_function` inherit from `decltype(is_function_impl_<T>(priority_tag<3>{}))`?

Comment: Answering my own question: Casey Carter [took care](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BTJ1JNfh5aPbFfvk) of that one.

Comment: @Barry Yes, Eric's implementation is certainly not without flaws. I decided to use the original version from the tweet for this question, but there is certainly room for improvement with regards to code clarity.

Comment: Regarding Casey's implementation, instantiating function templates is _expensive_. Why bother when you don't have to? I suspect my version compiles faster than Casey's. But I like @Barry's suggestion of changing the return types to `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`. Nice.

Comment: https://twitter.com/jlitb/status/856065093444022272

Comment: Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b655c530b381ec48

Comment: @EricNiebler proposed fix: `T[1]` instead of the `decltype` in the `[2]` version.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Right now the `decltype` in [2] is the only thing filtering out `char[]`. `T[1]` wouldn't work because you can't form the type `char[1][]`.

Comment: @quux darn. You are right. I forgot about those.

Comment: @Quuxplusone alternative: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2ced77d5c158cad

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: [That LGTM.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dlqOYxWU3seJS71q) I was wondering if your observation could be boiled all the way down to `is_function_v<T> == is_same_v<void(T), void(T*)> or else false`, but no, Casey's test case for `is_function_v<void() const && noexcept>` torpedoed that idea.

Comment: In the meantime, Alisdais Meredith came up with an implementation that [fits into a single tweet](https://twitter.com/AlisdairMered/status/861185981063581696). Maybe we should move the question over to [Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)... ;)

Comment: @comic I replied with an optimization to his tweet

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Nice catch :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone not sure whether you noticed it in the tweets, but we arrived at `template<class T> bool is_function_v = !is_const_v<const T> && !is_reference_v<T>;`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Indeed! I've included that short implementation in my work-in-progress "STL from Scratch" repo at https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/tree/master/include/scratch/bits/type-traits .

Comment: @Quuxplusone another abuse: https://wandbox.org/permlink/kfwImuwcVuXpHZD2

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### The general idea

Instead of listing all the valid function types, like the [sample implementation over on cpprefereence.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function), this implementation lists all of the types that are *not* functions, and then only resolves to `true` if none of those is matched.

The list of non-function types consists of (from bottom to top):

- Classes and unions (including abstract types)
- Anything that can be returned from a function (including `void` and reference types)
- Array types

A type that does not match any of those non-function types is a function type. Note that `std::is_function` explicitly considers callable types like lambdas or classes with a function call operator as *not* being functions.

### `is_function_impl_`

We provide one overload of the `is_function_impl` function for each of the possible non-function types. The function declarations can be a bit hard to parse, so let's break it down for the example of the *classes and unions* case:

```
template<typename T, typename = int T::*>
char(&is_function_impl_(priority_tag<3>))[4];
```

This line declares a function template `is_function_impl_` that takes a single argument of type `priority_tag<3>` and returns a reference to an array of 4 `char`s. As is customary since the ancient days of C, the declaration syntax gets horribly convoluted by the presence of array types.

This function template takes two template arguments. The first is just an unconstrained `T`, but the second is a pointer to a member of `T` of type `int`. The `int` part here does not really matter, ie. this will even work for `T`s that do not have any members of type `int`. What it does though is that it will result in a syntax error for `T`s that are not of class or union type. For those other types, attempting to instantiate the function template will result in a substitution failure.

Similar tricks are used for the `priority_tag<2>` and `priority_tag<1>` overloads, which use their second template arguments to form expressions that only compile for `T`s being valid function return types or array types respectively. Only the `priority_tag<0>` overload does not have such a constraining second template parameter and thus can be instantiated with any `T`.

All in all we declare four different overloads for `is_function_impl_`, which differ by their input argument and return type. Each of them takes a different `priority_tag` type as argument and returns a reference to a char array of different unique size.

### Tag dispatching in `is_function`

Now, when instantiating `is_function`, it instantiates `is_function_impl` with `T`. Note that since we provided four different overloads for this function, overload resolution has to take place here. And since all of these overloads are function *templates*, that means [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) has a chance to kick in.

So for functions (and only functions) all of the overloads will fail except the most general one with `priority_tag<0>`. So why doesn't instantiation always resolve to that overload, if it's the most general one? Because of the input arguments of our overloaded functions.

Note that `priority_tag` is constructed in such a way that `priority_tag<N+1>` publicly inherits from `priority_tag<N>`. Now, since `is_function_impl` is invoked here with `priority_tag<3>`, that overload is a *better match* than the others for overload resolution, so it will be tried first. Only if that fails due to a substitution error the next-best match is tried, which is the `priority_tag<2>` overload. We continue in this way until we either find an overload that can be instantiated or we reach `priority_tag<0>`, which is not constrained and will always work. Since all of the non-function types are covered by the higher prio overloads, this can only happen for function types.

### Evaluating the result

We now inspect the size of the type returned by the call to `is_function_impl_` to evaluate the result. Remember that each overload returns a reference to a char array of different size. We can therefore use `sizeof` to check which overload was selected and only set the result to `true` if we reached the `priority_tag<0>` overload.

### Known Bugs

Johannes Schaub [found a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470741/how-does-eric-nieblers-implementation-of-stdis-function-work#comment74188378_43470962) in the implementation. An array of incomplete class type will be incorrectly classified as a function. This is because the current detection mechanism for array types does not work with incomplete types.

Comment: Pretty good explanation. In the "Evaluating the result" part I'd say something about how it's actually testing the size of the returned char array by the version of `is_function_impl` called. The version for function types returns an array of size 1, hence the check against `==1` against the result of the function call.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for the feedback, I tried to make that section a bit clearer. Feel free to edit the answer if you see further room for improvement.

Comment: Could `(*(T*)0)[0]` be replace by `std::declval<T>()[0]`?

Comment: I would like to know what template<typename T, typename = decltype((*(T*)0)[0])> does ?

Comment: It casts 0 to `T*`, dereferences it, then indexes into the resulting reference. This only works if `T` is a type that can be indexed, like an array. It could​ be replaced with `std::declval<T>()[0]`, but that would be more characters. :-)

Comment: Or use `std::is_array` for array specialization ? Or is there some magic that `is_array` would miss ?

Comment: Tried it on the wandbox example posted by @Barry in the comment section of the question. That works too. Awesome!

Comment: How is 

`template<typename T, typename = int T::*>`
`char(&is_function_impl_(priority_tag<3>))[4];`

a function declaration?  I'm having trouble parsing the return type and how the trailing [4] fits in to the usual function signature syntax

Comment: so on cdecl with code `char(&is_function_impl_(priority_tag))[4];`, the result is 

"declare is_function_impl_ as function (priority_tag) returning reference to array 4 of char."

Is a function body not needed?

Comment: @wes The function is never called, we just use `sizeof` to determine at compile time what the size of the return type would be if we were to call it. Therefore a declaration is sufficient, we do not need to define it.

Comment: @Arunmu wrote: _"Or use `std::is_array` for array specialization ? Or is there some magic that `is_array` would miss ?"_

Why instantiate a template when you don't have to?

Comment: @EricNiebler Ah..yes there is that. But it makes me sad because people will start making this argument (rightfully so) to make the code harder to read (but faster to compile and less bloated (?) )  even when the standard provides you with the traits to check that. Perhaps there should be a way to avoid needless instantiations and compiler should just see through the user intention ? Thats perhaps another topic. Anyways, awesome stuff, Sir!

Comment: Please consider adding my testcase to your answer, as an example of where the algorithm fails: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b655c530b381ec48

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I added it to the answer, thanks for pointing out. I did not understand how [your proposed fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470741/how-does-eric-nieblers-implementation-of-stdis-function-work#comment74188261_43470741) is supposed to work though. Feel free to edit the answer yourself with an explanation if you want.

Comment: @ComicSansMS in `T[1]`, the `T` can be an array type, but not a function type. That's all what we need to test.