# how is std::is_function implemented

Tags: c++, c++11

Per CPP reference, `std::is_function` can be implemented as follows. Can someone explain why this works as it seemingly does not directly address callables?

```cpp
template<class T>
struct is_function : std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    !std::is_const<const T>::value && !std::is_reference<T>::value
> {};
```

Comment: I doesn't need to. It's not about detecting general callable objects, just literal function types as defined by the core language. Those two checks are quirks of those types.

Comment: I have no idea how this works (probably just by exclusion of non-function types), but for callables, it doesn't address them on purpose, as per documentation: Types like std::function, lambdas, classes with overloaded operator() and pointers to functions don't count as function types

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470741/how-does-eric-nieblers-implementation-of-stdis-function-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It exploits this sentence from https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier#1

> A function or reference type is always cv-unqualified.

So, given a type `T`, it tries to make a `const T`. If the result is *not* a const-qualified type, then T must be a function or reference type. Then it  eliminates reference types, and done.

(not to be confused with member functions that have `const` in the end: that is, in standardese, "[a function type with a cv-qualifier-seq](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#10)", not the same as a "cv-qualified function type")